# How to provide feedback to the user than the button has been pressed while UI thread goes about its business

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have a JButton which launches a JFileChooser. However the JFileChooser often takes a few seconds to come up, during which time the user might think that nothing is happening. I tried to make the button become disabled until the JFileChooser is finished with, but the disabling of the button doesn't even happen until the JFileChooser is loaded. Is there something I can do?
My code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.err.println("clicked");
    ((JButton) e.getSource()).setEnabled(false);
    System.err.println("set");
    JFileChooser b = new JFileChooser("C:\\");
    b.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    int res = b.showOpenDialog((Component) e.getSource());
    if (res == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        try {
            //Blah
        }
        catch (Exception err) {
            JDialog j = new JDialog(window, "An error occured:\n" + err.getMessage());
        }
    }
    ((JButton) e.getSource()).setEnabled(true);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move these lines..

```
JFileChooser b = new JFileChooser("C:\\");
b.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
```

..from the action performed method to the constructor of the action listener, change them to..

```
b = new JFileChooser("C:\\");
b.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
```

..then declare..

```
private JFileChooser b;
```

..as a class attribute (so it is visible to the action performed method).

You might also want to give it a better name.

---

The chooser will be constructed when the class is created, and be ready for use when needed.  This has the added benefit that the chooser will remember the position, size, path & file display type, the subsequent times the user activates the button.

---

Yet another strategy is to declare the chooser as a class attribute, **don't** instantiate it in the constructor, but check in the action performed if it is `null`, and if so, create and configure it.

**Continued..**

---

> I might want to do something a bit slower like this at some point, that doesn't quite deserve its own thread.

With the last strategy I outlined, I was considering adding something that I will add now.

---

**..Continued**

..Of course, that last method will give exactly the same problem you describe, but just once when the user 1st clicks the button.  For that situation, you should probably be looking to pop a `JOptionPane` with an indeterminate `JProgressBar` from inside a `SwingWorker`.

Obviously, a `SwingWorker` creates a new `Thread`, but OTOH, `Thread` objects in Java are cheap.  There are  a number of them running for any app. with a GUI.  A couple more will not hurt.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much what I needed. Still, is there a way to do what I was trying to do? I get the impression that I might want to do something a bit slower like this at some point, that doesn't quite deserve its own thread.

Comment: Is there no easy way to just simply disable the button until the action is complete? I get the impression that even if I did the SwingWorker to do the slow part (in this case creating the JFileChooser), that either the action will finish before the JFileChooser loads, or the button still won't disable until its loaded anyway.

Comment: If you go for the approach where the file chooser is only created once, it is very user friendly if you store the directory from where the last file was chosen. The next time the user presses that button, you show the filechooser opened in that directory.

Comment: @Robin if you are re-using the same file chooser, it will retain the last directory (that it was in when closed) automatically.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks. I was not sure about this and too lazy to investigate this. Perhaps this time I will remember it :-)